# Maintain and Plan R&D Project Progress

Tags: windows, android, project-management, cross-platform

I am looking for a project management software with the following feature-

- It can maintain the daily progress of the project.
- I can enter the plan for the coming week (like a task planner or a calendar).
- Free/open source
- Must have a Windows and Android version (with sync feature).

The TickTick seems perfect, but it's not free for Windows.

Comment: This Question is vague. Are you after a task-tracker To-Do List, or actually project management? Study up on what project management actually means (task dependencies, resource allocation, partial completion, PERT charts, Gantt charts, etc.). Specify more details about your requirements and criteria.